# docker-compose not working on Azure App Service

Tags: python, django, azure, docker, celery

I have pushed 4 images to Azure Container Registry: django-app, celery-worker, celery-beats and nginx. I have created docker-compose file that I used to created images and I want to upload to Azure App Service but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in multi-container config parsing: YamlException: (Line: 12, Col: 9, Idx: 256) - (Line: 12, Col: 35, Idx: 282): Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.
```

**I changed WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to true**.

Below you can find docker-compose file I am uploading to Azure:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app.azurecr.io/app-app
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - backend/:/usr/src/backend/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env

  celery_worker:
    container_name: app.azurecr.io/app-celery_worker
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: celery -A app_settings worker --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log
    volumes:
      - backend:/usr/src/backend
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - app

  celery-beat:
    container_name: app.azurecr.io/app-celery-beat
    build: ./backend
    command: celery -A app_settings beat -l info
    volumes:
      - backend:/usr/src/backend
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - app

  nginx:
    container_name: app_nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./azure/nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - static:/home/app/web/static
      - media:/home/app/web/media
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  backend:
  static:
  media:
```

Below you can see my mouted storages I created in **Path mappings**:
[image]

I don't want to get rid of volumes because I want to store and persist files on Azure Storage. I'd like to know how to fix this error and learn what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Build and depends_on are unsupported features on App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#supported-options. Also, only one container can be exposed externally.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling with the same issue I found the solution in Microsoft docs, link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=debian#docker-compose-options).

What I did is:

1. Changed container_name to image.
2. Added EXPOSE 80 in my Dockerfile.
3. Changed ports in docker-compose to "80:80".
4. Build images once again, push and pull on Azure Container Registry.